# Change multiple HTML element from ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax  on success function where I wrote some css color changing task upon satisfying some conditions.I'm changing the html element's color using **"document.getElementById"**. My problem is that there should me more than one data object where html element should be change but in that case its always the last object.

My on success function:

```
            success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                if (userId == value.ApplicationUserId && postId == value.PostId && value.IsLiked == 1) {
                    document.getElementById(likeId).style.color = "red";
                }
                if (userId == value.ApplicationUserId && postId == value.PostId && value.IsLiked == 2) {
                    document.getElementById(dislikeId).style.color = "red";
                }
                if (userId == value.ApplicationUserId && postId == value.PostId && value.IsHelpfull == 1) {
                    document.getElementById(helpfulId).style.color = "red";
                }
            });
        }
```

And my element ID's are all unique and dynamically generated.Also I'm passing the right Id inside documet.getElementById. How can I change all elements satisfying the conditions ?

Comment: Are you sure `value.IsHelpfull` is not a typo?

Comment: I'm confused a little, do you want to change all three elements?

Comment: @leun4m its not a type for this code.same in all place.

Comment: @pilchard if they satisfy then all. But like and dislike cant be  1 and 2 at same time. So only two of them will change .

Comment: is it supposed to be `likeId` or `likedId` and the same for `dislikeId`

Answer (score 0):

Given your clarification in the comments it seems you want something like this.

First, since the first two conditions of all of your conditionals are the same, you can check those once and nest the other checks within it.

```
if (userId == value.ApplicationUserId && postId == value.PostId) {
    ...
}
```

Then, you have two separate cases to check:

1. If it's liked or disliked. Since these are mutually exclusive you can combine them with an `else`.

```
if (value.IsLiked == 1) {
    document.getElementById(likeId).style.color = "green"; // Liked color
} else if (value.IsLiked == 2) {
    document.getElementById(dislikeId).style.color = "red"; // Disliked color
}
```

2. If it's helpful

```
if (value.IsHelpfull == 1) {
  document.getElementById(helpfulId).style.color = "blue"; // Helpful color
}
```

---

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if (userId == value.ApplicationUserId && postId == value.PostId) {

      if (value.IsLiked == 1) {
        document.getElementById(likeId).style.color = "green";
      } else if (value.IsLiked == 2) {
        document.getElementById(dislikeId).style.color = "red";
      }

      if (value.IsHelpfull == 1) {
        document.getElementById(helpfulId).style.color = "blue";
      }

    }
  });
}
```

---

**ps:** check that your spelling of `helpful` is consistent and correct throughout.